# unable to initialize snowflake data source

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, ruamel.yaml, great-expectations, snowflake-connector

I am trying to access the snowflake datasource using "great_expectations" library.

The following is what I tried so far:

```
from ruamel import yaml

import great_expectations as ge
from great_expectations.core.batch import BatchRequest, RuntimeBatchRequest

context = ge.get_context()



datasource_config = {
    "name": "my_snowflake_datasource",
    "class_name": "Datasource",
    "execution_engine": {
        "class_name": "SqlAlchemyExecutionEngine",
        "connection_string": "snowflake://myusername:mypass@myaccount/myDB/myschema?warehouse=mywh&role=myadmin",
    },
    "data_connectors": {
        "default_runtime_data_connector_name": {
            "class_name": "RuntimeDataConnector",
            "batch_identifiers": ["default_identifier_name"],
        },
        "default_inferred_data_connector_name": {
            "class_name": "InferredAssetSqlDataConnector",
            "include_schema_name": True,
        },
    },
}

print(context.test_yaml_config(yaml.dump(datasource_config)))
```

I initiated great_expectation before executing above code:

```
great_expectations init
```

but I am getting the error below:

```
great_expectations.exceptions.exceptions.DatasourceInitializationError: Cannot initialize datasource my_snowflake_datasource, error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create_engine'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration seems to be ok, corresponding to the example [here](https://github.com/great-expectations/great_expectations/blob/develop/tests/integration/docusaurus/connecting_to_your_data/database/snowflake_python_example.py).

If you look at the traceback you should notice that the error propagates starting at the file `great_expectations/execution_engine/sqlalchemy_execution_engine.py` in your virtual environment.

The actual line where the error occurs is:

```
            self.engine = sa.create_engine(connection_string, **kwargs)
```

And if you search for that `sa` at the top of that file:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

make_url = import_make_url()
except ImportError:
        sa = None
```

So sqlalchemy is not installed, which you
don't get automatically in your environement if you install greate_expectiations. The thing to do is to
install snowflake-sqlalchemy, since you want to use sqlalchemy's snowflake
plugin (assumption based on your connection_string).

```
/your/virtualenv/bin/python -m pip install snowflake-sqlalchemy
```

After that you should no longer get an error, it looks like `test_yaml_config` is waiting for the connection
to time out.

What worries me greatly is the documented use of a deprecated API of `ruamel.yaml`.
The function `ruamel.yaml.dump` is going to be removed in the near future, and you
should use the `.dump()` method of a `ruamel.yaml.YAML()` instance.

You should use the following code instead:

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

import great_expectations as ge
context = ge.get_context()

datasource_config = {
    "name": "my_snowflake_datasource",
    "class_name": "Datasource",
    "execution_engine": {
        "class_name": "SqlAlchemyExecutionEngine",
        "connection_string": "snowflake://myusername:mypass@myaccount/myDB/myschema?warehouse=mywh&role=myadmin",
    },
    "data_connectors": {
        "default_runtime_data_connector_name": {
            "class_name": "RuntimeDataConnector",
            "batch_identifiers": ["default_identifier_name"],
        },
        "default_inferred_data_connector_name": {
            "class_name": "InferredAssetSqlDataConnector",
            "include_schema_name": True,
        },
    },
}

yaml = YAML()

yaml.dump(datasource_config, sys.stdout, transform=context.test_yaml_config)
```

I'll make a PR for great-excpectations to update their documentation/use of `ruamel.yaml`.